# Extender a imagem fora do container do lado esquerdo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tenho um container, que dentro dele tem um bloco dividido ao meio.
Do lado esquerdo preciso fazer que a imagem saia do container.
Seria este modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com essa estrutura:

```html
 <div class="blog_section">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
     <img src="images/exames/imagem/exame.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
     <div class="abt_txt abt_txt_resp texto_exame med_toppadder50">Texto ....></div>
    </div>   
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

O que consegui foi o container-fluid, mas ele expande o lado direito também...

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "fazer que a imagem saia do container" como assim, sair do container? Vc que que ela fica por cima da outra coluna de texto? O que mais exatamente vc está com dúvida?

Comment: Desculpe. Realmente não estava didático. Agora eu marquei o container. A imagem, eu precisaria que saia do container. Deve ter algum termo para isso, mas seria isso.

Answer (score 0):

Seria assim que gostaria que ficasse:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="blog_section">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
     <img src="https://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/assets/blog_es/ideia.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
     <div class="abt_txt abt_txt_resp texto_exame med_toppadder50">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dui est, hendrerit sit amet dui a, porttitor gravida lorem. Aenean eget dolor sed leo convallis imperdiet.<br><br>
             Pellentesque sed erat in eros finibus varius. Sed sit amet augue non tortor aliquam fermentum eu vel tellus. Suspendisse facilisis laoreet ex at bibendum.<br><br>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dui est, hendrerit sit amet dui a, porttitor gravida lorem. Aenean eget dolor sed leo convallis imperdiet.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
           
      </div>   
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```